# Why can't I find a tool that lowers the priority of background processes in Windows?

Tags: google-chrome, cpu, autohotkey, cpu-usage

Since I have started using Windows 10, I contantly have lots of applications open on different desktops. I for example, often have a dozen WinSCP instances open. Each of these take up a few percent of CPU even when the window is not active. This is clearly a bug in that application, but there are also many others that behave in the same way. Therefore, I would like to find an application that can automatically reduce the priority (or completely halt) any application that which is not in focus currenly. I would also love it if that worked for Chrome, so that background windows would not take up any CPU (maybe except for Gmail and Facebook).

I cannot understand that I can't find this, as it should not be hard to implement in for example Autohotkey (well the Chrome part might).

Such a tool would also significantly increase battery life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool that tries such automatic "tweaks". It is called [Process Lasso](https://bitsum.com/processlasso/):

> ProBalance - Keep your PC responsive during high CPU loads!
>   Real-time CPU affinity and process priority optimization!

Look if this tool does what you want.

You should also look for a Windows Store app version of the tools that you care about. If you leave such a store app, it gets suspended and only runs shortly in background to receive data.

Answer (score 0):

The windows task manager has this capability built in - although it's not automatic.

Open the task manager (Control-alt-delete), go to the Details tab, NOT the processes tab! The Details tab is actually the replacement of what was the processes tab in Windows 7 and XP. Anyway, find your process in that list, look at the descriptions for help, and then right click on the process, and then hover over "Set Priority", and you can change it to Low, which should reduce it's usage. I think this only works however if your CPU usage is already at 100%, otherwise it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ok. I did not know that it does not do anything unless the CPU usage is 100%, so maybe setting the process priority is not the perfect solution to this (though a decent one at least). It has to be an automatic tool, though has it gets too tedious to do this manually all the time.

Comment: Unfortunately, you generally just have to hope that windows manages the CPU resources well, which is simply often doesn't. Furthermore, windows doesn't really allow software to change things at such a low-level

Comment: I think that this would be quite easy to do in Autohotkey. I know that one can change the priority of a process from command line, so it is possible to automate.

Comment: Yes, there are command line options to control process priority, but first it would be difficult to program, and secondly, it still does exactly the same thing that the task manager does.